# Greek letters in facet_wrap labels for Plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, facet

I have been trying to transfer a ggplot using `facet_wrap`, for which I have labels and their greek letters to a Plotly plot using `ggplotly`. This, however, leads to the facet labels only displaying their unparsed expression.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# Get exemplary expression.
mpg$class[mpg$class == 'compact'] <- 'beta[0]'
mpg$class[mpg$class == '2seater'] <- 'alpha[0]'

p <- ggplot(mpg[mpg$class %in% c('beta[0]', 'alpha[0]'),], aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point()

p <- p + facet_wrap(vars(class), labeller = label_parsed)    
     
p # These facet labels work as intended. 

ggplotly(p) # This will produce facet labels with the unparsed expression.
```

How would I go about adding the desired format (greek letters and subscript) in the Plotly output?

Comment: `mpg$class[mpg$class == 'compact'] <- "\u03B1"` for alpha and 
`mpg$class[mpg$class == '2seater'] <- "\u03B2"` for beta

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Would it be possible to get the subscripts ```[0]``` (0 in this case) in there as well using your method?